# Adding Search Capabilities to my website

Tags: php, api, search

Instead of writing a PHP script from scratch, I wanted to know if there are any free scripts, plugins, or APIs out there that allow me to add a search box to my website to search only content on my site.

Google's free version is ad-supported, and I am looking for a clean, simple, and non ad-supported solution. Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.sphider.eu/ possibly?

Comment: or http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733980/how-do-i-do-a-search-on-my-website , or choose another one from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the zend lucene extension. It provides a PHP interface to the open source Apache Lucene search engine.

Zend_Search_Lucene Documentation:
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

Apache Lucene project:
http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of these, one of them are [sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super easy way that works pretty well:

http://sitecomber.com/getsitecomber/

You can create code to paste into your site in about 2 minutes.  It doesn't get easier than that.  Search is powered by Google, but results are isolated to your website.